# Lambda can't do Int16 comparisons?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have the following `lambda expression` in my c# (.NET 4.7.1) code:

```
DataRow[] skmRows = dtSKM.AsEnumerable().Where(x =>
   x.Field<int>("NDRAWING1").Equals(NDRAWING1) &&
   x.Field<Int16>("NDRAWING2").Equals(NDRAWING2)
   ).ToArray();
```

Everything compiles and no exceptions are thrown at runtime. The problem is that the lambda expression above should get results--but it doesn't. I stopped on a breakpoint and verified that matching `DataRows` should have occurred.

So then I copied this expression into the `Immediate` window in `VS2017` and ran it--and it **DID** get matching DataRows. WTH??

So then I got wondering about that `Int16`. The related column in MSSQL is a `SMALLINT`, which maps to INT16 in C#. For kicks, I changed the datatype in sql server from smallint to int, and changed my lambda thusly:

```
DataRow[] skmRows = dtSKM.AsEnumerable().Where(x =>
   x.Field<int>("NDRAWING1").Equals(NDRAWING1) &&
   x.Field<int>("NDRAWING2").Equals(NDRAWING2)
   ).ToArray();
```

...and it worked!! (I got the matching rows as expected.)

This leads me to conclude that there is a bug in .NET in which the runtime cannot correctly evaluate Int16 comparisons against smallint sql server column values.

Is there an explanation besides *bug*? I am guessing this should be easy for anyone to repro. Whip up a lambda to match against a SMALLINT column in MSSQL and see what happens.

Comment: Could be a mapping issue or something in your code. It is hard to tell without an [mcve]. You would need to provide the mapping structure, DDL, and EF (i think you are using EF some how?) as well as the models (what is `Field<T>(string)` as an example)

Comment: This worked fine against a manually constructed `DataTable`. What are some of your values for NDRAWING1/2?

Comment: you need to provide more information, the snippet you have chosen isn't enough to determine the problem.  What types does the data table think it has? ( screen shot a debug?). You should show the code for  the declaration of NDRAWING2, clearly showing the type, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that **smallint** maps to **int16** aka **short**. You can verify it at [adonet server data type mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings). As for what is happening, check the documentation of int16 equals : ["true if obj is an instance of Int16 and equals the value of this instance; otherwise, false."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings).

The variable **NDRAWING2** needs to be **int16** as well. In Javascript there is operator "===" to denote that value needs to be the same and the type.

---

With proper abstraction, using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 2.2.6 and NUnit 3.2, i will:

- create in memory database context
- add context to service
- use service to add some data and store them to db
- verify it has some data in a new context
- use service to find the data I want
- verify it did find the data

A code example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DtSkmContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Add_writes_to_database")
            .Options;

        using (var context = new DtSkmContext(options))
        {
            var service = new DtSkmService(context);
            service.Add(3, 7);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new DtSkmContext(options))
        {
            Assert.That(context.DtSkm.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));

            var service = new DtSkmService(context);
            var result = service.Find(3, 7);

            Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
        }
    }
}
```

The service

```
public class DtSkmService
{
    private DtSkmContext _context;

    public DtSkmService(DtSkmContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Add(int ndrawing1, Int16 ndrawing2)
    {
        var dtSkm = new DtSkmDto { Ndrawing1 = ndrawing1, Ndrawing2 = ndrawing2 };
        _context.DtSkm.Add(dtSkm);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IEnumerable<DtSkmDto> Find(int first, Int16 second)
    {
        return _context.DtSkm
            .Where(b => b.Ndrawing1.Equals(first) && b.Ndrawing2.Equals(second))
            .OrderBy(b => b.Ndrawing1)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

and dto and context

```
public class DtSkmDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Ndrawing1 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int16 Ndrawing2 { get; set; }
}
public class DtSkmContext : DbContext
{
    public DtSkmContext()
    {
    }
    public DtSkmContext(DbContextOptions<DtSkmContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<DtSkmDto> DtSkm { get; set; }
}
```

While this uses EF core and in memeory db, it shows one way how to do it. In your case you can make a small change of:

```
var data = dtSKM.AsEnumerable().ToList();
DataRow[] skmRows = data.Where(x =>
   x.Field<int>("NDRAWING1").Equals(NDRAWING1) &&
   x.Field<Int16>("NDRAWING2").Equals(NDRAWING2)
   ).ToArray();
```

and you can verify the data instance types/values with a debugger. One of your assumptions does not hold and it is not the "bug in .NET".

Comment: Margus, I'm puzzled...it seems like you're simply restating what I originally stated. NDRAWING2  WAS Int16, but no matches were found. So I had to change it to int in the DB and in the code. I'm not sure how you're really giving a solution. Did you look carefully at my original lambda in my post? It is Int16 there, and it doesn't work. In other words, what code change are you suggesting to make it work as an Int16?

Comment: @HerrimanCoder in your original post you don't show how `NDRAWING1` and `NDRAWING2` (as in `Equals(NDRAWING1)`) are declared. You say "For kicks, I changed the datatype in sql server from smallint to int, and changed my lambda thusly:" but you don't say you changed the type of the constant `NDRAWING2`. Hence the need for @Margus to clarify this.

Comment: Daniel, excellent question...I cannot remember whether I defined NDRAWING2 as an `int` or `Int16`. If I defined it as Int16, then the mystery remains. But if I absentmindedly defined it as an int and then tried to use it in lambda as an Int16, then the mystery is solved. I changed it to an int a few days ago and changed the counterpart column in mssql to int, to get everything working. And now I can't remember how I originally had it. :-(